# What are the requirements and responsibilities of a mod?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Just want to start off by saying no, I'm not asking if I can be *recommended* for becoming a Mod. I'm just curious as to what's involved.

I have to say, first of all: time flies when you're having fun. I recently was awarded with the Fanatic badge, without even realising just how much time I spend on this site.

I have done a fair amount (though probably minuscule compared to some) of reviewing, and monitoring, answering and asking, and all through that time, the little diamond next to Mods' names has got me wondering, what are (if any) the requirements of Mods on a Stack Exchange site?